# How to make swipe function on listview (react-native)?

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native, mobile-development

I have list of items. I am using [ListView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) for it and I need to be able to delete any row by swiping left or right.

Where can I start from here?

Comment: I seem to get faster, better, and more answers when I [include just a little snippet of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). probably because it is much easier for others to copy/paste/modify rather than writing an example from scratch, and programmers can more generally read the code to quickly see the problem regardless of what language in which the question was written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer, follow [this guide](https://medium.com/@bddougie/adding-swipe-to-delete-in-react-native-cfa85a5f5a31#.m9zv5t3kz) which uses [React Native Swipeout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipeout).

Otherwise, here's my SwipeList and SwipeListRow component.  I partially use my library [Cairn](http://github.com/adamterlson/cairn) for styling, but it should be easily translated into a normal React Stylesheet if you care to do so:

## SwipeList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, ListView } from 'react-native';
import styleContext from 'app/style';

const style = styleContext.extend({
    listViewSection: {
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingLeft: 15,
        backgroundColor: '$greyDefault'
    },

    'text.listViewSection': {
        color: '$greyMid',
        fontSize: 16,
        marginLeft: 5
    }
});

function SwipeList({ dataSource, renderRow }) {
    function renderSectionHeader(sectionData, sectionId) {
        return (
            <View {...style('listViewSection')}>
                <Text {...style('text.listViewSection')}>{sectionId.toUpperCase()}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    if (!dataSource.rowIdentities.length) {
        return (
            <Text>No items found.</Text>
        );
    }

    return (
        <ListView
            dataSource={dataSource}
            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
            directionalLockEnabled
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={false}
            keyboardDismissMode={'on-drag'}
            renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
            renderRow={renderRow} />
    );
}

SwipeList.propTypes = {
    dataSource: React.PropTypes.shape({
        rowIdentities: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
    }).isRequired,
    renderRow: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default SwipeList;
```

---

## SwipeListRow.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    ScrollView,
    Animated,
    Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

import styleContext from 'app/style';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const style = styleContext.extend({
    swipeMessage: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        height: 75,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    itemContainer: {
        width
    }
});

const WHITE = 0;
const GREEN = 1;
const AnimatedScrollView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ScrollView);

class SwipeListRow extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            color: new Animated.Value(WHITE)
        };
    }

    animateScroll = (e) => {
        const threshold = width / 5;
        let x = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
        let swiped = null;

        x = x * -1;

        if (x > -50 && this.swiped !== WHITE) {
            swiped = WHITE;
        } else if (x < -50 && x > -threshold && this.swiped !== GREEN) {
            swiped = GREEN;
        }

        if (swiped !== null) {
            this.swiped = swiped;

            Animated.timing(this.state.color, {
                toValue: swiped,
                duration: 200
            }).start();
        }
    }

    takeAction = () => {
        if (this.swiped) {
            Animated.timing(this.state.color, {
                toValue: WHITE,
                duration: 200
            }).start();

            this.props.onSwipe();
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { swipeEnabled, swipeMessage, children } = this.props;
        const bgColor = this.state.color.interpolate({
            inputRange: [
                WHITE,
                GREEN
            ],
            outputRange: [
                'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                'rgb(123, 204, 40)'
            ]
        });

        return (
            <View>
                <AnimatedScrollView
                    horizontal
                    directionalLockEnabled
                    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                    onScroll={this.animateScroll}
                    scrollEventThrottle={16}
                    scrollEnabled={swipeEnabled}
                    onMomentumScrollBegin={this.takeAction}
                    style={[{ flex: 1 }, { backgroundColor: bgColor }]}>
                    <View>
                        <View {...style('itemContainer')}>
                            {children}
                        </View>
                        <View
                            {...style(
                                'swipeMessage',
                                [{ width: width / 5, right: -width / 5 - 20 }]
                            )}>
                            <Text {...style('text.bold text.white')}>{swipeMessage}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </AnimatedScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

SwipeListRow.propTypes = {
    children: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    onSwipe: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    swipeEnabled: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    swipeMessage: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};


export default SwipeListRow;
```

With these components, now all you must do is pass in the required datasource as you would to a normal list view, as described on the [ListView component documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html).

```
    <SwipeList
        dataSource={dataSource}
        renderRow={(item) => (
            <SwipeListRow
                key={item.id}
                swipeMessage={'Delete Item'}
                onSwipe={() => deleteItem(item)}
                swipeEnabled={true}>
                <<< INSERT DISPLAY OF ROW HERE >>>
            </SwipeListRow>
        )} />
```

Comment: Can you, please, share full example how to use it? Because I have an error: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kIswK.png

Answer (score 0):

use this one

[react-native-swipe-list-view](https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view)

This works really good and you can scale to anything.

Comment: I have tried to follow your recommendation but their Snack is broken, markdown examples have bad synthax, SwipeListExample can't build for android after cloning the source and following the guide, how can I use it for web/ios and android? https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view/issues/401