# How we create the list View Swipeout in React native

Tags: react-native

I want to create a swipeour in listView in React native.I use this link
 [ListView Swipeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393453/how-to-make-swipe-function-on-listview-react-native) to create 
But this link not working.Please give me the code to create a swipout as in this link https://medium.com/@bddougie/adding-swipe-to-delete-in-react-native-cfa85a5f5a31

Answer (score 0):

The above link you have shared works fine on ios ,but not on android.
I have tried using React Native swipe list view

Usage Snippet:

```
import { SwipeListView } from 'react-native-swipe-list-view';
render() {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    return (
        <SwipeListView
            dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(dataSource)}
            renderRow={ data => (
                <View style={styles.rowFront}>
                    <Text>I am {data} in a SwipeListView</Text>
                </View>
            )}
            renderHiddenRow={ data => (
                <View style={styles.rowBack}>
                    <Text>Left</Text>
                    <Text>Right</Text>
                </View>
            )}
            leftOpenValue={75}
            rightOpenValue={-75}
        />
    )
}
```

Refer the below link for more:
https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view